# How to form a dictionary of dictionaries with keys/values built from 3 different lists in Ansible

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

I'm pulling a data file off several remote hosts that has *dynamically* named columns and then rows of data. I'd like to compute a consolidated data structure. I cannot get json or csv from the source, just a text data file.

NODE1

```
field1  field2  field3
valueA1 valueA2 valueA3
```

NODE2

```
field1  field2  field3
valueB1 valueB2 valueB3
```

So far, I built 3 lists: The 1st is a list of node names. The 2nd & 3rd are formed from the data file on each host. The column names are the same in each data file, but I currently just build List2 with redundant names throughout as I read the remote data file.

List1

```
- node1
- node2
- node3
```

List2 of list

```
-
    - field1
    - field2
    - field3
-
    - field1
    - field2
    - field3
-
    - field1
    - field2
    - field3
```

List3 of list

```
-
    - valueA1
    - valueA2
    - valueA3
-
    - valueB1
    - valueB2
    - valueB3
-
    - valueC1
    - valueC2
    - valueC3
```

I'd like to end up with a dictionary of dictionaries like this:

```
{ node1: 
    {field1:valueA1, field2:valueA2, field3:valueA3},
  node2: 
    {field1:valueB1, field2:valueB2, field3:valueB3},
  node3:
    {field1:valueC1, field2:valueC2, field3:valueC3}
}
```

Suppose I could use a different data structure, but ultimately, I need the data nested like this into a variable for use later in the playbook and ultimately saved to a json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more options:

- Use filter *community.general.dict*. For example, given the lists

```yaml
list1: [node1, node2, node3]
list2: [field1, field2, field3]
list3:
  - [valueA1, valueA2, valueA3]
  - [valueB1, valueB2, valueB3]
  - [valueC1, valueC2, valueC3]
```

the declaration below

```yaml
result: "{{ dict(list1|
                 zip(list3|
                     map('zip', list2)|
                     map('map', 'reverse')|
                     map('community.general.dict'))) }}"
```

does the job

```yaml
result:
  node1: {field1: valueA1, field2: valueA2, field3: valueA3}
  node2: {field1: valueB1, field2: valueB2, field3: valueB3}
  node3: {field1: valueC1, field2: valueC2, field3: valueC3}
```

---

- Optionally, use Jinja. For example, given the lists

```yaml
list1: [node1, node2, node3]
list2:
  - [field1, field2, field3]
  - [field1, field2, field3]
  - [field1, field2, field3]
list3:
  - [valueA1, valueA2, valueA3]
  - [valueB1, valueB2, valueB3]
  - [valueC1, valueC2, valueC3]
```

The declarations below give the same result

```yaml
result_str: |-
  {% for keys,values in list2|zip(list3) %}
  {{ list1[loop.index0] }}:
  {% for k,v in keys|zip(values) %}
    {{ k }}: {{ v }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
result: "{{ result_str|from_yaml }}"
```

---

- Given the simpler *list2* with one set of the keys only

```yaml
list1: [node1, node2, node3]
list2: [field1, field2, field3]
list3:
  - [valueA1, valueA2, valueA3]
  - [valueB1, valueB2, valueB3]
  - [valueC1, valueC2, valueC3]
```

The declarations below give the same result

```yaml
result_str: |-
  {% for values in list3 %}
  {{ list1[loop.index0] }}:
  {% for k,v in list2|zip(values) %}
    {{ k }}: {{ v }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
result: "{{ result_str|from_yaml }}"
```

Comment: This looks great and I figured it could be accomplished by a series of exotic (to me) Jinja2 data translations, however I get this error. I'm using Ansible 2.9.10

`no filter named 'community.general.dict'`

Comment: I'm in an Internet-disconnected environment at that location, so it might be I don't have access to any 'community.general.*' namespaces

Comment: 2.9 is EOL. Collections included 'community.general' are included since 2.10.

Comment: I'm stuck with a RHEL version and an environment where I cannot use community.* filters/modules. I ended up using Frenchy's custom filter solution

Comment: ...but I would have definitely used your solution Vladimir if I could have. Probably should have mentioned my OS/env limitations in the OP

Comment: I added a simple example without 'community.general'.

Comment: take a bow, because you should for 3 reasons: 1) coming back to overcome my limitation against community.general, 2) providing a nice in-line solution that I can put directly in a playbook, and 3) your solution creates values that are interpreted are numbers, not strings, which is something I was chasing down to fix with the custom filter solution. I gladly use your code now

Answer (score 1):

this playbook does the job (using jinja2):

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    list1:
      - node1
      - node2
      - node3
    list2:
      - - field1
        - field2
        - field3
      - - field1
        - field2
        - field3
      - - field1
        - field2
        - field3
    list3:
      - - valueA1
        - valueA2
        - valueA3
      - - valueB1
        - valueB2
        - valueB3
      - - valueC1
        - valueC2
        - valueC3
  tasks:
    - name: loop over lists
      set_fact:
        list4: >-
            {%- set ns = namespace() -%}
            {%- set ns.dico = {} -%}
            {%- for l1 in list1 -%}
            {%- set ll = loop -%}
            {%- set ns.l1 = {} -%}
            {%- for l2 in list2 -%}
            {%- set ns.d2 = {} -%}            
            {%- for sl2 in l2 -%}
            {%- if ns.d2.update({sl2: list3[ll.index0][loop.index0]}) -%}{%- endif -%}                       
            {%- endfor -%}
            {%- if ns.dico.update({l1: ns.d2}) -%}{%- endif -%} 
            {%- endfor -%}
            {%- endfor -%}
            {{ ns.dico }}
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list4 }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "node1": {
            "field1": "valueA1",
            "field2": "valueA2",
            "field3": "valueA3"
        },
        "node2": {
            "field1": "valueB1",
            "field2": "valueB2",
            "field3": "valueB3"
        },
        "node3": {
            "field1": "valueC1",
            "field2": "valueC2",
            "field3": "valueC3"
        }
    }
}
```

you could use too a custom filter (full python script):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'listzip': self.listzip
        }

    def listzip(self, l1, l2, l3):
        result = {
            node: {
                    field: value for field, value in zip(l2[idx], l3[idx])
                } for idx, node in enumerate(l1)
        }
        return result
```

and you use it like this:

```
- name: loop
  set_fact:
    list4: "{{ list1 | listzip(list2, list3) }}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ list4 }}"
```

Comment: Since this is pure built-in Ansible functionality, It might be easiest to use your suggestion. I like the custom filter implementation, but am getting jumbled results that are not the expected format. Kind of looking into it now to determine why.

Comment: becareful your list2 and list3 are list of lists and if you use jinja2, respect {%- and -%}

Comment: Yeah, I had List2 incorrectly called when I used your code; in a lot of the other test code here, they were using just one slice of List2, which I invoked as List2[0] for testing. After taking it out when using your code as List2, everything works. Yours is a great solution and works with the limitations of my environment for this task (probably should have mentioned those limitations in the OP). I would have used Vladimir's solution, but I cannot get access to community.* filter and modules

Comment: glad to help you..one thing the Vladimir's solution is not an answer to your problem..the initial list2 is not the same than yours

Comment: Right. I'd have to slice mine as List2[0] to feed into his code. All the List2[x] are the same in my use case

Answer (score 1):

First, note that your file format is actually csv compatible and can be read with the `read_csv` plugin

Given the following inventory for local test purpose:

```yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
  hosts:
    node1:
    node2:
    node3:
```

and faking target files as `/tmp/test_files/nodeX_file.txt` on my local machine (same content as the one you pasted above).

The following playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    test_file_path: /tmp/test_files/

  tasks:
    - name: load content from test file on each host
      read_csv:
        delimiter: " "
        skipinitialspace: true
        path: "{{ test_file_path }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}_file.txt"
      register: field_values

    - name: Show the result
      vars:
        relevant_raw_data: "{{ hostvars | dict2items | selectattr('value.field_values', 'defined') }}"
        relevant_keys: "{{ relevant_raw_data | map(attribute='key') }}"
        relevant_values: "{{ relevant_raw_data | map(attribute='value.field_values.list') | map('first') }}"
        dict_result: "{{ relevant_keys | zip(relevant_values) | items2dict(key_name=0, value_name=1) }}"
      debug:
        var: dict_result
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

gives:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [load content from test file on each host] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [node2]
ok: [node3]
ok: [node1]

TASK [Show the result] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [node1 -> localhost] => {
    "dict_result": {
        "node1": {
            "field1": "valueA1",
            "field2": "valueA2",
            "field3": "valueA3"
        },
        "node2": {
            "field1": "valueB1",
            "field2": "valueB2",
            "field3": "valueB3"
        },
        "node3": {
            "field1": "valueC1",
            "field2": "valueC2",
            "field3": "valueC3"
        }
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
node1                      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
node2                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
node3                      : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I simplified things a bit with my description. My source files have a a lot of preamble free-form text and then the data table inside it, so I'm not getting the pure file like my OP description. I'm using `awk` to pluck the set of data out of the file into the format I showed.

I could overcome that to create a suitable intermediate file and use your code, unfortunately, in the environment at this location, I cannot use any `community.general.*` filters/modules

Comment: `community.general` is available out of the box in any decently recent ansible version (i.e. 2.10 and onward). Moreover, I used short module names and I'm quite sure those will be available even in an outdated and EOL ansible version (i.e. 2.9 and lower).

Comment: While I didn't test with your code, because of the csv aspect I mentioned, I'm probably not able to use those community.* modules because the OS we're using for this task is RHEL. I ended up using Frenchy's custom filter solution

Comment: Once again, there is no `community.*` module directly referenced in my answer (I used short names only) and the vast majority of those modules were available as core before 2.10 hence contained in the system packages still distributed on RHEL rpms. Moreover, even on an outdated RHEL system you can `pip install ansible` (instead of yum) to get a still supported ansible version (my 2 cent: whatever the distro, don't use system packages for ansible, they are systematically outdated). Meanwhile, the important thing in the end is that you have a solution meeting your requirements.